# Soap UI load testing

Tags: web-services, soapui, load-testing

I want to call the webservice multiple times passing different parameter, 
e.g. getDetail(Id) , by reading the ids from an excel sheet or a constant.
I understand you can do this by writing groovy script in SoapUI, does anyone have a working example to start with.

PS: I am using the free SoapUI version and not SoapUI  Pro.

Comment: Is "id" the only parameter that changes?  Will each thread use the same id/params for each run through the test?

Comment: Yes id is the only parameter that needs to be passed to the service, they the list of ids is pretty static.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this would be to have Test Case with 3 steps.

The first one: a groovy script step that does something like this:

```
['111', '222', '333'].each {
    com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.globalProperties.setPropertyValue('id', it)
    testRunner.runTestStepByName("testRequest")
}
testRunner.gotoStepByName('done')
```

Secondly the Test Request step. Inside the request you can refer to the id parameter by ${id}

and thirdly an empty Groovy script step 'done' for jumping out of there.

Instead of the static list you can get the test ids from a file.

Answer (score 0):

We achieve this by using a groovy script step at the start of our test:

```
switch (context.ThreadIndex) {
    case 0: context.Id = 'id for thread 1 here'; break;
    case 1: context.Id = 'id for thread 2 here'; break;
    ...
    default:
       log.error 'Thread['+context.ThreadIndex+'] Run['+context.RunCount+']: no Id available for assignment'
}
```